# How to find keys by pattern which must start with specific string and contain value at any place of keyname?

Tags: redis

I have a key in Redis:

```
travelpayouts-special-offers---origin=MOW-destination=MCX-locale=en
```

Is that possible to find all such keys where `locale=en` considering it can be virtually anywhere in the key string? I.e. pattern should be able to find all of those keys:

```
travelpayouts-special-offers---origin=MOW-destination=MCX-locale=en
travelpayouts-special-offers---origin=MOW-locale=en-destination=MCX
travelpayouts-special-offers---locale=en-origin=MOW-destination=MCX
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `*locale=en*` as the pattern to feed `SCAN` / `KEYS` with.

```bash
> SCAN 0 MATCH *locale=en*
1) "0"
2) 1) "travelpayouts-special-offers---origin=MOW-destination=MCX-locale=en"
   2) "travelpayouts-special-offers---locale=en-origin=MOW-destination=MCX"
   3) "travelpayouts-special-offers---origin=MOW-locale=en-destination=MCX"
```